# Convert special characters to normal characters using PHP, like ã, é, ç to a, e, c

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I would like to convert special characters to normal characters using PHP.

For example.

```
ã, á, à, é, ç, ...
```

to

```
a, a, a, e, c, ...
```

It would be great if someone could help me with the issue I'm having.

Comment: What is a "PHP special character"?

Comment: And what is a “normal character”?

Comment: I guess you're looking for "php slugify" or "php urlize". Google it.

Comment: I guess he is rather [looking for some kind of transliteration](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+transliteration).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ts = array("/[À-Å]/","/Æ/","/Ç/","/[È-Ë]/","/[Ì-Ï]/","/Ð/","/Ñ/","/[Ò-ÖØ]/","/×/","/[Ù-Ü]/","/[Ý-ß]/","/[à-å]/","/æ/","/ç/","/[è-ë]/","/[ì-ï]/","/ð/","/ñ/","/[ò-öø]/","/÷/","/[ù-ü]/","/[ý-ÿ]/");
$tn = array("A","AE","C","E","I","D","N","O","X","U","Y","a","ae","c","e","i","d","n","o","x","u","y");
preg_replace($ts,$tn, $p);
```

Make an array of the special characters and an array of the regular character and use preg_replace() on the string like above.

Comment: i wanna to know how to covert special character string like â ëåñó ðîäèëàñü åëî÷êà in php